# Remove empty list item with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which is dynamically built, but there are empty list items which need removing.

```
<ul>
<li>www</li>
<li>www</li>
<li>www</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

How do I do this with JQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('ul li').filter(function() {return $(this).text()​​​​​​​ == '';}).remove();​
```

Answer (score 18):

```
$('ul li:empty').remove();
```

Comment: won't work with, for example, `<li><span></span></li>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').find('li').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':empty'))
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Please use Andy's implementation (above mine :))